# What's the difference between coherent states and quasi-classical states?

Tags: coherent-states

It's actually a trouble in translation. I got an essay about "some state" that relate to classical states, but we don't have many textbook in our language to compare.
I only know that it's an eigenstate of annihilation operator. Searching on many English textbook gives me  2 concepts, "coherent states" and "quasi-classical states". So what the difference between them?
Thank you.